# ng-cloak not woking on page load

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-cloak to hide the content on page load but it is not working.
My code is:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" ng-hide="searchForm">
 <div class="panel-heading">SELECT USERS FOR NOMINATIONS IN TRAINING</div>
    <div ng-show="nominateUsers">
     <div class="panel-body">
       <select multiple ng-model="cattraining.user_id" style="width:300px; height:150px">
         <option ng-repeat="user in nominateUsers" value="{{user.id}}">{{user.name}}
        </option>
       </select>
     </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="fnominateUser(cattraining)">SUBMIT</a>
    </div>
   </div>
         <div class="panel-body" ng-show="!nominateUsers" ng-cloak>
                                <div class="alert" ng-cloak><strong>Oops, </strong>You don't have any user to nominate</div>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the CSS code related to the ngCloak directive ?

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Source : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak